# 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' Cannot find column 12

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015

The error is that it can't find column 12. But I already double checked that the spelling is the same as the one in database. I tried on a small sample like only the first 3 columns, it worked. But when I tried to use the file I needed to upload, it gave the error.

How do I fix it?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(CSV_CONNECTIONSTRING, csvPath)))
{
    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ["+File_Name+"]", con))
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
}

try
{
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConString))
    {
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, "medicine_id");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, "category_id");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, "subcategory_id");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(3, "med_name");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(4, "brand");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(5, "form_id");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(6, "poison_schedule");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(7, "strength");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(8, "image");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(9, "quantity");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(10, "unit");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(11, "threshold");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(12, "price");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(13, "manufacturer");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(14, "special_instructions");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(15, "active1");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(16, "active1_strength");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(17, "active2");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(18, "active2_strength");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(19, "active3");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(20, "active3_strength");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(21, "active4");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(22, "active4_strength");

        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "medicine";
        bulkCopy.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
        bulkCopy.Close();
    }
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: How do you get the source table `dt`? Does it have the 23 columns you expect?

Comment: This is the code i used to get dt                                                                             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(CSV_CONNECTIONSTRING, csvPath)))
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ["+ File_Name+"]", con))
                        {
                            da.Fill(dt);
                        }'

Comment: Look at your _File_Name_ using a text editor or load it in excel as a csv. Does it have for each row 23 columns?

Comment: yup there is 23 columns in each row

Comment: the error is still the same

Comment: Could it be that some rows contain 23 columns, but with empty values and thus SqlBulkCopy ignores empty values?

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, SqlBulkCopy ignores nulls, this should solve the problem if you are bringing back null values.

Edit: Credit to Igor Labutin, I didn't see his comment before posting.

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls))
```

Comment: And when you set a breakpoint and debug, what do you see vs what is expected?

Comment: apparently when i changed the file name to the one i used before for testing, the error was gone. but it came out a new error which is Column ' ' does not allow DBNull.Value. does that mean i need to change them to nulls?

Comment: Are you sure that the order of the fields in source and target are identical?

Comment: yes. i've checked many times. For example, my file has only 8 rows, but when i try to upload it came out the error Column ' ' does not allow DBNull.Value. so, i tried changing it to null. when i checked the database, there are alot of rows that is not even in the file and majority of it are all nulls. They show that it has the medicine id then the rest are nulls. But i only have 8 medicine in the csv file.